# The documentation reads 'Wire adapters and JS functions are built on top of LDS'. What is an adapter?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lightning-data-service

The documentation reads- Wire adapters and JavaScript functions in these modules are built on top of Lightning Data Service (LDS) and User Interface API. Use these wire adapters and functions to work with Salesforce data and metadata.
[source](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_ui_api)

I want to know what exactly is an adapter? What does it mean when we say wire adapter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the programming sense, an adapter is a class whose methods act as an interface between two interfaces.

In LWC, The `@wire` decorator takes two parameters:

```
@wire(adapter, config)
```

The Salesforce LWC documentation glosses over this, but if we look at LWC OSS, we learn that an [adapter](https://lwc.dev/guide/wire_adapter) is a class with three methods: `connect`, `disconnect`, and `update(config)`. It is required to have `constructor` with one parameter, the callback that should be called when new data is available.

You can see this in action in this [LWC OSS wire adapter demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/xgVZyAoSpYIKSjuhSIBm/src/utils.js?p=stories) I wrote. Here's a sample implementation:

```
class SampleWireAdapter {
  connected = false;
  callback;
  constructor(callback) { 
    this.callback = callback;
  }
  connected() {
    this.connected = true;
  }
  disconnected() {
    this.connected = false;
  }
  update(config) {
    if(this.connected) {
      callback({data:'Hello World!',error:undefined});
    }
  }
}
```

`update` is called at least once to initialize the data stream, and then will be called continually as the configuration is updated through reactivity (`{param:'$someVariable'}`).

In Salesforce LWC, these adapters are auto-generated from the available Apex methods and platform adapters, such as the CurrentPageReference adapter. In LWC OSS, you can use this to call API methods from any arbitrary server or call any arbitrary method, and return the data in manner expected by the component.